# r program portfolio / lm FUNCTION

Tags: r, linear-regression, beta

So my question is in regards to a tutorial set up by... https://www.r-bloggers.com/investment-portfolio-analysis-with-r-language/

the section is:

```
lm.MMM<- lm(MMM_ExcessR ~ SP500_ExcessR,df)
```

.. but it does not seem to work. lm is the linear regression ... so im trying to conduct the regression to get the beta of MMM. 
the error is --->

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class""function"" to a data.frame
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change `df` to `exReturn`. Probably a mistake from the author.

Comment: Thank you so much it works.